# Responsive Bootstrap Dropbown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new in programming,and I decided to start designing a website. While coding, I found an issue: I can't make the dropdown menu look OK. I'll leave a picture of how it looks and the code I wrote, so you can help me!
Thank you in advance!

[image]

HTML

```css
img{max-width:100%;}
.quitar-float{float: none;}
.espacio-arriba{margin-top: 100px;}
#principal{
  width:40%;
  float:none;
  margin-top:100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#otro_elemento{margin-top:100px;}
.ingreso:hover{color:white;}
.img-responsive{margin: 0 auto;}
.ingreso{
  font-size:240%;
  color:black;
}
.menu{color:#B40000;}
body{
  font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
  color:#B40000;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
  border-color: white;
  background-image: url(https://http2.mlstatic.com/cesped-bermuda-gramilla-brasilera-envios-a-mvdeo-D_NQ_NP_20364-MLU20188773672_102014-F.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
.links{font-size: 20em;}
.espacio-derecha{margin-right: 1em;}
.se-gris{background-color: #eee;}
.padding-largo{padding:5px 10px;}
.inline-block{
  float:none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -6px;
}
.no-lista{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.no-lista li{list-style-type:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Club Atlético Rivadavia</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Days+One" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav no-lista se-gris inline-block padding-largo">
                <li class="dropdown col-md-2"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">El Club<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Disciplina</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Comisión directiva</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#">Fútbol</a></li>
                <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#">Estadio</a></li>
                <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#">Sede</a></li>
                <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#">Fútbol infantil</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown col-md-2"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Polideportivo<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Básquet</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hockey</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Natación</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean under "I can't make the dropdown menu look OK"? What is "OK" for you?

Comment: It's not occuping all the screen, but just the half of it

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `nav` with the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">El Club<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Disciplina</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Comisión directiva</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Fútbol</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Estadio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sede</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fútbol infantil</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Polideportivo<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Básquet</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hockey</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Natación</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of assumptions in my attempt to solve your problem. But, you for sure need to read more about Bootstrap and what `col-md-*` mean.

Have a look:

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
  background: url(https://http2.mlstatic.com/cesped-bermuda-gramilla-brasilera-envios-a-mvdeo-D_NQ_NP_20364-MLU20188773672_102014-F.jpg) center center no-repeat fixed /cover;
}
nav{
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  margin:10px;
  padding:5px 10px;

}
.inline-block{
  float:none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Days+One" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav inline-block">
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">El Club<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Disciplina</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Comisión directiva</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Fútbol</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Estadio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sede</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fútbol infantil</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Polideportivo<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Básquet</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hockey</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Natación</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</body>
```